# C++ Verify template type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Sorry for my poor english I'll try to do my best.

I want to design an interface that should be used like this:

```
class MyObject : public IMyInterface<MyObject>
{
    // ...
};
```

The interface could look like this:

```
template <class _TMyObject>
class IMyInterface
{
    virtual _TMyObject* Get() = 0;
};
```

What i'm looking after, is a way to verify, at compile time, that the interface is used as intended.
How can I test if `_TMyObject` "is-a" `IMyInterface<_TMyObject>`? Inside the interface definition, with a static_assert for example.

Thanks for any help :).
Have a nice day!

Comment: You mean you want to make sure someone doesn't to e.g. `class MyObject : public IMyInterface<SomeUnrelatedObject>`?

Comment: By the way, and totally unrelated to your question: Symbols with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_TMyObject`) are *reserved* in all scopes by the C++ specification for the "implementation" (compiler and standard library). See [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more information.

Comment: `You mean you want to make sure someone doesn't to e.g. class MyObject : public IMyInterface<SomeUnrelatedObject>?` Yes that's it.

And thanks for the naming conventions link!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to make such a protection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't put `static_assert` inside the class itself, because `D` is an incomplete type, but you can put it in the destructor (or constructor, but there can be many constructors):

```
template<class D>
struct B
{
    ~B()
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<B, D>);
    };
};

struct Not_E {};

struct D : B<D> { };         
struct E : B<Not_E> { };     

void foo()
{
     D d;     // OK
     E e;     // Fails
}
```

**Addition.** Note that this solution is not a complete protection against incorrect usage of CRTP. Please refer to **Some Programmer Dude**'s answer for a nice example of error that can't be caught by it.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, could you please explain why? I can't put `static_assert` inside the class, but when it is in the destructor (or constructor) MSVS and GCC do not complain.

Comment: Oooooh I tried this, but not in the destructor definition. I didn't work.
`error C2139: 'D': an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_base_of'`
What is the difference?

Comment: @diccy, `D` is incomplete at that point, but it will be complete at the point when `~B()` is instantiated.

Comment: So in this case, it even works to do `static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<B<D>, D>);` :)

Comment: @diccy, `B` and `B<D>` are the same inside `B`.

Comment: @diccy Note that this allows things like `struct F : B<D> { };`

Comment: Yeah sure, you are right ^^'.
Next step: if I do `struct F : B<D>`, the static_assert doesn't moan. Seems logic, as D fulfill the requirements. But I feel like I can't protect this case in the interface context.

Comment: @Rakete1111, I'd rather too, but how can you do it so that it works automatically for all `B<D>` instantiations?

Answer (score 3):

Since C++11 there are [many type property traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_properties) that could be used to do checks at compile-time.

For example [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) which in your case could be used like perhaps

```
template<typename TChild>
struct IMyInterface
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<IMyInterface, TChild>::value, "Derived class not derived from IMyInterface");

    // ...
};
```

<sub>Note: The exact code shown above will not work directly, but rather show the principle.</sub>

Of course, that do allow something like

```
class MyFirstClass : public IMyInterface<MyFirstClass>
{
    // ...
};

//                        Note wrong class in template
//                                        vvvvvvvvvvvv
class MySecondClass : public IMyInterface<MyFirstClass>
{
    // ...
};
```

So to answer your question if it's possible for such a check: Not really the way you want. Even using other traits and meta-programming, you can never guarantee that the template argument for the interface class is "correct" when used in the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

The only way I can see it work is by using down-casting at run-time with `dynamic_cast`, something like `dynamic_cast<TChild*>(this) != nullptr` in the interface class.